# How to pass scheme name to PgSQL function?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 (can move to 12 if needed).

I have many schemes with same table_name, so I want to pass scheme_name to functions like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.test()
RETURNS TABLE(base_name text, slow real)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT * FROM scheme_name.bases, scheme_name.servers
    WHERE scheme_name.bases.id = scheme_name.servers.id;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
  DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.test;
    CREATE FUNCTION public.test(scheme_name character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(base_name text, scheme_name text)
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
        AS $$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
        'SELECT ' ||scheme_name||'.bases.base_name, ' ||scheme_name||'.servers.scheme_name FROM ' ||param||'.bases,'||param||'.servers'
        ' WHERE ' ||scheme_name||'.stations.id = ' ||scheme_name||'.servers.id';
    $$;
```